# Rails: search through a very nested associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to find a flight where arrival airport IATA code equals the specified, here's schema:

```
 create_table "flights", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "route_id"
    t.datetime "departure"
    t.datetime "arrival"
    t.decimal "price"
    t.integer "airplane_id"
  end

  create_table "routes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "departure_airport_id"
    t.integer "arrival_airport_id"
  end

  create_table "airports", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "iata_code"
    t.string "icao_code"
    t.string "international_name"
    t.string "localized_name"
  end
```

The association from route to airport looks like this

```
class Route < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :arrival_airport, :class_name => "Airport"
  belongs_to :departure_airport, :class_name => "Airport"
```

And there is no inverse on the Airport class. I tried this one

```
@search_results = Flight
                        .joins(:route)
                        .joins(:arrival_airport)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close.

```
@search_results = Flight
                    .joins(route: :arrival_airport)
                    .where(airports: {iata_code: my_iata_code})
```

Checkout the [Rails Query Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables) for more details. Especially around 12.1.3.1 Joining Nested Associations (Single Level).

Comment: No, I get a `PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "arrival_airport" `

Comment: Oops, that should be the table name, not the relation name in the conditions. TBH, it can probably be removed altogether because iata_code should be unique among the joined tables. (Updated my answer)

Comment: What if I want to find by departure airports then?

Comment: Just change the join to `.joins(route: :departure_airport)`.

Comment: I mean, combined in a single query?

Comment: Hey, it worked fine and answers the question,  but I can't make it work when I specify a departure_airport in the same query

Comment: It gets a little complicated. I'll amend my answer again.

Comment: Not so complicated. This worked: `.where(departure_airports_routes: {iata_code: params[:from]})` Thanks